Git keeps thinking I'm logged in as the wrong user
I am trying to push some changes from Terminal to my repository, but it keeps getting denied as it thinks I'm logged in with my other user account despite trying countless times to logout / login with the correct account.
Below a summary of where I'm at.
Notice that '22222222' represents the correct account whereas 11111111 is the incorrect account (the one I can't seem to log out of).
git status

On branch main
Your branch and 'origin/main' have diverged,
and have 1 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean


git push

remote: Permission to 22222222/22222222.git denied to 11111111.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/22222222/22222222.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403


git remote -v

origin  https://github.com/22222222/22222222.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/22222222/22222222.git (push)

Also if I do git fetch origin then Terminal just outputs a blank line.
Update
I've removed my Git login details from Keychain Access on my Mac (I read somewhere to try that), now when I try git push it prompts me for login details.
But I'm using the login details for the 22222222 and they keep getting rejected, even though I'm pasting what I have saved in my Chrome passwords manager.

Check for the default user name with git config --list.

@9769953 Thanks, I've tried that but I cant actually see any username listed in there? Although bear in mind I have just deleted my Keychain Access for Git from my Mac

Since it now asks for your login details, perhaps you should configure git to use a specific user name? You can set one per repository (git config user.name "username") or globally git config --global user.name "username"). You may have to enter your password the first time, but hopefully it gets stored again in the keychain. But if you have varying logins for different repositories, I'm not sure Keychain will be able to handle that; to Keychain, it might all be git (the program), not individual repositories.

@9769953 Ive just tried that but it still prompts for username and password and rejecting them. I've even tried resetting my Git password incase I was using the wrong one, but still getting permission denied!

There are multiple mechanisms at play here. What worked for me (but even then not always, apparently because of how the Keychain caches identities on the Mac? I'm still not entirely sure) was to define the account to use in each repo's settings.

Logging in is probably pointless; instead what I do is set the SSH command per repo to use ssh -I .ssh/1111111111 instead of just ssh. I'm not at my computer so I'm afraid I have to be vague on the details. Anyway, there are several existing questions about this on Stack Overflow, though none of them had answers which worked 100% for me.

@9769953 user.name/user.email are not authorization credentials. They're commit identification data. They're used during commit creation and never used during pull/push. Logins/passwords, access tokens, SSH keypairs are authorization credentials.

So after a lot of searching it turned out I needed to set a Personal Access Token, instead of my password, as per the following video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMEyBtsuAJE&list
Im not sure why I couldn't just enter my password however

Explanation (for security purpose): https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/

@Philippe Thanks! I really can't understand why Git doesn't make it more clear, could have saved myself and so many others a lot of time

git doesn't make it more clear because it has nothing to do with git, it's a GitHub thing.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
